# $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: limits, functions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, pointwise-convergence

I have to calculate

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

---

I'm thinking of using the dominated convergence theorem. So I define

$$f_n(x)=\frac{n^2 x \sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3}.$$

$f_n$ are measurable owing to the fact that they are continuous. Now, I have to calculate its limit. If I'm not wrong:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2 x \sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3}
= (x\sin{x}) \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{1+(nx)^3}
= (x\sin{x}) \cdot 0
=0.$$

So $|f_n(x)|\le0$ and using the dominated convergence theorem:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} n^2 \frac{x\sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 \frac{x\sin{x}}{1+(nx)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} 0 \, \mathrm{d}x =0
\end{align*}

Is it ok?

Comment: If $|f_n(x)|\leq 0$, then $f_n$ is identically zero, which is of course false. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: Oh, that's true. So how can I calculate that limit? What can I use for it? @SangchulLee

Comment: Thankfully,  your approach can be salvaged by noting that $(f_n)$ is dominated by a constant function: Using $\left|\sin x\right|\leq\left|x\right|$, we get $$\left|f_n(x)\right|\leq\frac{(nx)^2}{1+(nx)^3}=\frac{1}{\frac{nx}{2}+\frac{nx}{2}+\frac{1}{(nx)^2}}\stackrel{\text{(AM-GM)}}\leq\frac{2^{2/3}}{3}.$$ So, the use of the dominated convergence theorem is justified and the answer is $0$.

Comment: what is AM-GM? @SangchulLee

Comment: It is the [AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). If you are not familiar with this, you may inspect the behavior of the function $$g(t)=\frac{t^2}{1+t^3}$$ and show that $g(t)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

$|f_n(x)| \leq 0$ is certainly false.  It is true that $f_n (x) \to 0$ for each $x$.

If $x\leq \frac 1  n$ then $|\frac {n^{2}x \sin x} {1+n^{3}x^{3}}|\leq n^{2}x \sin x\leq 1$ since $\sin x \leq x$. If $x >\frac  1n$ then $|\frac {n^{2}x \sin x} {1+n^{3}x^{3}}|\leq |\frac {n^{2}x \sin x} {n^{3}x^{3}}|\leq \frac  1 {nx}\leq 1$. Hence, $|f_n(x) | \leq 1$ in both cases.  Hence, the limit of the integral is $0$ (by DCT).

Comment: So which is the solution? 1?

Comment: @User160 See my answer now.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? Where is the mistake?